# When exactly does the OnItemUpdated event fire specifically in a FormView in ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, event-handling, webforms

I can't for the life of me figure out when OnItemUpdated gets fired. I've been messing around in ASP.NET trying to learn it, so some of the things you see in this code might be purposely done the hard way (so I can better understand whats going on behind the scenes)

Basically, I have a GridView that is the master control that uses a formview as a detail.

Here is the `SelectedIndexChanged` method for `GridView`

```
protected void GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var context = new DataAccessLayer.SafetyEntities();
    var se = (from c in context.Employees
                  where c.EID == (long)GridView1.SelectedDataKey.Value
                  select c).ToList();
    FormView1.DataSource = se;
    FormView1.DataKeyNames = new string[] { "EID" };
    FormView1.DataBind();
}
```

That's working fine, it displays the selected details in the form for editing. This is what the `formview` looks like:

```
<asp:FormView ID="FormView1" runat="server" DefaultMode="Edit" OnItemUpdating = "FormView1_ItemUpdating" OnItemUpdated="BLAH">
    <ItemTemplate>
        Select an employee!
     </ItemTemplate>
     <EditItemTemplate>
         <table>
             <tr>
                 <th>Name: 
                 </th>
                    <td>
                        <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID ="NameEdit" Text='<%#Bind("Name") %>' /> 
                    </td>
                    <br />
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>Manager: 
                </th>
                <td>
                    <asp:DropDownList ID = "DDLEdit1" DataSourceID = "ManagerEntitySource" runat="server"
                           DataTextField = "Option_Value" DataValueField = "Option_Value"
                           SelectedValue = '<%#Bind("Manager") %>'  
                           AppendDataBoundItems="true">
                    </asp:DropDownList> 
                </td>
                <br />
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>Location: 
                </th>
                <td>
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="DDLEdit2" DataSourceID = "LocationEntitySource" runat="server"
                           DataTextField = "Option_Value" DataValueField = "Option_Value"
                           SelectedValue='<%#Bind("Building") %>' 
                           AppendDataBoundItems="true">
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                </td>
                <br />
        </table>
        <asp:Button ID="Button2" Text="Submit Changes" runat="server" CommandName="Update" />
            <!--<asp:LinkButton ID = "LB1" Text="Update" CommandName="Update" runat="server" /> -->
    </EditItemTemplate>       
</asp:FormView>
```

This works as well. You can see from the attributes of the `FormView` that I specify `OnItemUpdating` and `OnItemUpdated`.

Here is `OnItemUpdating`:

```
protected void FormView1_ItemUpdating(object source, FormViewUpdateEventArgs e)
{
   DebugBox.Text = FormView1.DataKey.Value.ToString();
   DataAccessLayer.SafetyEntities se = new DataAccessLayer.SafetyEntities();
   var key = Convert.ToInt32(FormView1.DataKey.Value.ToString());
   DataAccessLayer.Employee employeeToUpdate = se.Employees.Where(emp => emp.EID == key).First();
   employeeToUpdate.Name = e.NewValues["Name"].ToString();
   employeeToUpdate.Manager = e.NewValues["Manager"].ToString();
   employeeToUpdate.Building = e.NewValues["Building"].ToString();
   se.SaveChanges();
   GridView1.DataBind();

}
```

This works fine as well. The items are being updated appropriately and the `GridView` is refreshing.

Here is `OnItemUpdated`:

```
protected void BLAH(object source, FormViewUpdatedEventArgs e)
{
    DebugBox2.Text = "BLAH!!!!";
}
```

And here is the problem. This never gets called! Am I missing a step somewhere to get this event to fire? I thought I understood that the button would call Command="Update" which would fire ItemUpdating and then ItemUpdated. Its definitely calling ItemUpdating, but thats it. Do I need something additional to fire ItemUpdated?

Comment: Take a look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.formview.onitemupdated.aspx it talks a bit about using the FormView and may have the details you need.

Comment: @TimothyRandall nope...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Conclusion:**

Looking at the source code of the `FormView` class it seems that the `ItemUpdated` event is not fired when using DataBinding.

The `ItemUpdated` event only gets fired when you set the `SelectMethod`, `UpdateMethod`, `DeleteMethod` or `InsertMethod` properties of the `FormView`.

**The proof**

When you're updating an item in your `FormView` its 'UpdateItem' method is called which internally calls `HandleUpdate`.

```
public virtual void UpdateItem(bool causesValidation)
    {
      this.ResetModelValidationGroup(causesValidation, string.Empty);
      this.HandleUpdate(string.Empty, causesValidation);
    }

private void HandleUpdate(string commandArg, bool causesValidation)
    {
       // Lots of work is done here
    }
```

At the bottom of the `HandleUpdate` method, the `OnItemUpdating` event is triggered:

```
this.OnItemUpdating(e);
```

which is then followed by a rather curious line of code:

```
if (e.Cancel || !bindingAutomatic)
          return;
```

This in turn is followd by a call to `Update` on the `dataSourceView`.

```
dataSourceView.Update((IDictionary) e.Keys, (IDictionary) e.NewValues, 
(IDictionary) e.OldValues, 
new DataSourceViewOperationCallback(this.HandleUpdateCallback));
```

We can see that the last parameter of the Update method takes a callback which in this case is `HandleUpdateCallback`. `HandleUpdateCallback` is the place where our `OnItemUpdated` event is finally triggered.

```
private bool HandleUpdateCallback(int affectedRows, Exception ex)
    {
      FormViewUpdatedEventArgs e1 = new FormViewUpdatedEventArgs(
                                                       affectedRows, ex);
      e1.SetOldValues(this._updateOldValues);
      e1.SetNewValues(this._updateNewValues);
      e1.SetKeys(this._updateKeys);
      this.OnItemUpdated(e1);
      // A lot of other stuff goes on here
     }
```

So, that's the map of how we eventually get to the `OnItemUpdated` method being executed but why isn't it being executed in our case?

Let's skip back a little but to the "curious" part of the `HandleUpdate` method I mentioned earlier:

```
if (e.Cancel || !bindingAutomatic)
          return;
```

What's going on here? We're not cancelling our event but what about `!bindingAutomatic`, what's happening there?

The value is set further up in the `HandleUpdate` method:

`bool bindingAutomatic = this.IsDataBindingAutomatic;`

This property, `IsDataBindingAutomatic`, is an internal property on the `BaseDataBound` class (a base class bit further up the chain from our `FormView` class):

```
  protected internal bool IsDataBindingAutomatic
    {
      get
      {
        if (!this.IsBoundUsingDataSourceID)
          return this.IsUsingModelBinders;
        else
          return true;
      }
    }
```

Since we're not using a `DataSourceID` we end up returning the value of `IsUsingModelBinders`. This is a virtual property on the `BaseDataBoundControl` that is overriden in the `CompositeDataBoundControl` class, the base class that our `FormView` directly inherits from.

Now we get to the bit of code that directly determines whether our `OnItemUpdating` method will be fired:

```
protected override bool IsUsingModelBinders
    {
      get
      {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.SelectMethod) 
            && string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.UpdateMethod) 
            && string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.DeleteMethod))
          return !string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.InsertMethod);
        else
          return true;
      }
    }
```

This is basically saying that if we've set a SelectMethod, an UpdateMethod, or a DeleteMethod (these are string properties on the FormView) then return true, otherwise tell us if we've set an InsertMethod. In our case we haven't set any of these properties up and so we get a return value of `false`.

Because this is false, our curious piece of code from twice earlier simply returns and never reaches the part of the code that triggers the ItemUpdated event.